# Converting JSON to TRs and TDs

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a json call using .getJSON(); that returns this json:

```
{
  "frames":[ 
    { "0":[ " 46.01", " 47.00", " 50.01", " 49.01", " 50.00", " 50.00", " 49.01", " 48.00", " 48.01", " 49.04", " 47.01", " 48.01", " 47.04", " 46.01", " 48.01", " 46.01", " 48.04", " 46.01", " 46.01", " 48.01", " 46.01", " 48.00", " 46.01", " 48.00", " 46.00", " 49.00", " 45.00", " 47.00", " 48.00", " 50.00", " 49.00", " 50.00", " 49.01", " 50.00", " 48.01", " 49.01", " 46.01", " 46.00", " 48.00", " 45.00", " 45.01", " 48.01", " 49.01", " 48.01", " 46.01", " 46.01", " 48.04", " 49.04", " 47.01", " 47.04", " 47.01", " 46.01", " 46.00", " 44.00", " 44.00", " 45.01", " 45.01", " 44.01", " 44.00", " 44.01", " 43.00", " 43.00", " 45.01", " 45.00", " 44.01", " 44.01", " 45.00", " 45.01", " 45.01", " 46.01", " 48.01", " 47.00", " 49.00", " 49.01", " 46.01", " 48.01", " 48.04", " 47.01", " 49.01", " 45.04", " 46.01", " 48.04", " 46.00", " 47.04", " 47.00", " 46.01", " 46.04", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 45.01", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 47.01", " 49.01", " 48.00", " 49.01", " 49.01", " 49.01", " 47.01", " 46.01", " 48.01", " 46.01", " 48.00", " 48.01", " 49.01", " 47.04", " 46.00", " 45.04", " 46.01", " 45.01", " 47.01", " 45.01", " 47.01", " 45.01", " 48.01", " 47.01", " 45.00", " 44.01", " 48.01", " 45.00", " 44.00", " 46.00", " 45.00", " 45.00", " 45.00", " 48.01", " 42.01", " 43.05", " 44.05", " 45.01", " 45.04", " 44.00", " 45.01", " 50.01", " 50.01", " 50.00", " 51.01", " 50.01", " 50.00", " 51.01", " 52.00", " 51.00", " 51.00", " 51.00", " 51.00", " 51.01", " 50.01", " 50.01", " 48.00", " 47.00", " 48.01", " 48.00", " 51.01", " 48.00", " 47.01", " 48.00", " 48.01", " 49.01", " 46.00", " 48.00", " 48.01", " 46.00", " 49.00", " 49.00", " 49.00", " 49.00", " 49.01", " 49.00", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 47.01", " 50.00", " 47.04", " 48.00", " 48.01", " 47.00", " 46.01", " 48.01", " 49.00", " 48.01", " 46.01", " 46.01", " 49.01", " 47.01", " 47.01", " 47.04", " 46.01", " 48.01", " 45.01", " 44.01", " 45.04", " 44.01", " 45.10", " 46.01", " 44.05", " 45.04", " 47.01", " 45.00", " 46.00", " 48.04", " 46.00", " 49.01", " 48.01", " 47.01", " 47.00", " 47.01", " 49.01", " 47.01", " 47.01", " 48.00", " 48.00", " 46.01", " 46.01", " 48.00", " 50.00", " 48.00", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 48.00", " 47.01", " 47.04", " 47.04", " 49.04", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 48.01", " 47.00", " 45.04", " 46.04", " 45.01", " 48.01", " 46.04", " 49.00", " 48.01", " 47.01", " 49.01", " 48.01", " 46.00", " 47.01", " 47.00", " 48.01", " 47.01", " 47.01", " 50.01", " 48.00", " 48.01", " 49.01", " 49.01", " 47.01", " 48.04", " 49.04", " 48.01", " 50.01", " 48.01", " 49.01", " 44.01", " 45.01", " 44.01", " 45.01", " 46.04", " 44.01", " 44.01", " 43.00", " 44.01", " 45.00", " 46.01", " 44.00", " 45.04", " 43.01", " 45.01", " 47.01", " 45.01", " 45.00", " 44.01", " 46.01", " 46.01", " 47.01", " 47.01", " 46.01", " 46.01", " 45.10", " 46.04", " 45.04", " 45.01", " 45.01", " 45.04", " 46.04", " 46.04", " 43.05", " 44.05", " 43.10", " 44.10", " 45.04", " 46.01", " 44.05", " 45.10" ]},
    { "1":[ " 69.03", " 64.07", " 61.03", " 64.07", " 62.03", " 63.01", " 62.03", " 64.07", " 63.07", " 64.07", " 66.03", " 65.03", " 65.07", " 66.03", " 65.01", " 67.03", " 68.03", " 67.07", " 69.07", " 64.03", " 67.03", " 66.03", " 67.03", " 66.03", " 67.07", " 62.03", " 70.03", " 68.01", " 66.01", " 67.03", " 66.00", " 65.01", " 64.01", " 63.01", " 66.01", " 65.03", " 67.01", " 66.00", " 65.01", " 67.00", " 69.00", " 65.01", " 65.00", " 67.00", " 70.01", " 64.01", " 62.01", " 64.01", " 64.00", " 66.00", " 63.00", " 64.01", " 63.01", " 64.00", " 64.01", " 64.01", " 65.03", " 66.01", " 65.01", " 66.03", " 70.00", " 66.03", " 66.01", " 65.01", " 67.03", " 68.03", " 69.01", " 65.03", " 65.03", " 65.01", " 62.00", " 63.00", " 60.00", " 62.01", " 63.00", " 62.00", " 61.01", " 60.00", " 59.01", " 64.01", " 62.00", " 62.01", " 61.00", " 60.01", " 62.01", " 61.00", " 62.01", " 61.00", " 63.00", " 64.01", " 63.00", " 62.00", " 62.00", " 60.01", " 63.01", " 64.00", " 62.01", " 60.01", " 59.00", " 64.01", " 63.01", " 63.01", " 59.01", " 63.01", " 61.01", " 62.03", " 60.01", " 64.00", " 67.03", " 64.00", " 63.00", " 64.01", " 62.01", " 65.01", " 63.01", " 65.01", " 63.00", " 64.00", " 64.00", " 65.00", " 64.00", " 64.00", " 65.00", " 65.00", " 65.01", " 66.01", " 65.01", " 64.00", " 67.01", " 68.00", " 69.00", " 64.01", " 66.00", " 67.01", " 69.03", " 63.07", " 64.07", " 70.01", " 66.07", " 69.07", " 69.07", " 68.03", " 68.01", " 71.06", " 68.01", " 68.03", " 68.03", " 65.03", " 65.03", " 67.01", " 67.00", " 69.03", " 66.03", " 66.01", " 65.01", " 68.03", " 69.00", " 67.01", " 67.01", " 67.00", " 70.01", " 68.00", " 65.00", " 68.01", " 66.00", " 67.00", " 67.01", " 66.00", " 68.00", " 68.01", " 67.01", " 68.01", " 69.00", " 64.01", " 68.01", " 68.00", " 67.01", " 68.00", " 68.00", " 67.00", " 67.01", " 65.01", " 67.00", " 67.01", " 64.00", " 65.00", " 64.00", " 66.01", " 65.03", " 67.01", " 67.01", " 69.01", " 67.03", " 70.01", " 66.01", " 69.01", " 68.03", " 69.00", " 68.00", " 70.00", " 71.01", " 65.01", " 69.00", " 67.01", " 64.00", " 64.01", " 67.00", " 71.01", " 66.00", " 66.00", " 66.00", " 66.01", " 68.03", " 68.01", " 71.01", " 67.01", " 65.01", " 69.01", " 66.03", " 65.03", " 64.01", " 64.03", " 64.01", " 64.01", " 62.01", " 63.01", " 62.01", " 63.01", " 64.01", " 63.00", " 64.01", " 64.00", " 61.00", " 64.00", " 61.01", " 62.00", " 62.00", " 63.01", " 64.01", " 63.00", " 63.01", " 64.01", " 63.00", " 64.00", " 63.01", " 64.00", " 64.01", " 63.01", " 61.00", " 61.01", " 63.01", " 62.00", " 63.01", " 62.00", " 63.01", " 65.01", " 61.00", " 63.01", " 63.03", " 71.01", " 67.01", " 66.00", " 65.00", " 66.00", " 67.00", " 67.01", " 68.01", " 67.01", " 69.03", " 68.03", " 68.01", " 67.00", " 68.01", " 66.01", " 64.00", " 66.00", " 65.01", " 66.01", " 66.00", " 64.00", " 63.00", " 63.01", " 64.01", " 66.01", " 65.01", " 65.01", " 66.01", " 66.03", " 66.01", " 66.01", " 63.03", " 65.03", " 67.01", " 65.03", " 65.03", " 64.01", " 65.01", " 64.03", " 65.01", " 65.01" ]}
  ]
}
```

I need to produce the following:

a `<tr>` with the 0 index as a class and each value as a `<td>` ...

```
<tr class="0"> 
  <td>46.01</td>
  <td>47.00</td>
  <td>50.01</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="1"> 
  <td>69.03</td>
  <td>64.07</td>
  <td>61.03</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do in JavaScript:

```
var rowsHtml = response.frames.map(function(obj, index){
    var rowData = obj[index];
    var rowHtml = '<tr class="'+index+'">';
    rowHtml += rowData.map(function(num){
        return '<td>'+num+'</td>';
    });
     rowHtml+= '</tr>';
});
```

That should generate what you are saying. The 'rowsHtml' should be a string that you can append as "innerHtml" to any element on the page. Or, using jquery, you can turn it into html and append it as an element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, am I missing something, http://jsfiddle.net/7apLym1m/